# Mirrored Triangle

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am required to display a mirrored triangle like so:

```
0 1 2
  0 1
    0
```

But I am only able to get

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
3
```

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong and everything I've looked at only shows the star pattern, no number patterns. here is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i ++) {
    for(int j = i; j <= size; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: BTW, **javascript != java**. I have edited the [tag:javascript] tag out. Next time don't use it if it is a java question lest you get downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line, you have to print the leading spaces before printing the numbers. So you need two inner `for` loops, one for the spaces and one for the numbers:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    // first print out the leading spaces
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    // then print out the numbers
    for(int j = 0; j <= size - i; j++) {
       System.out.print(j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you, that makes so much more sense. Every time I tried to add a space it would either not show or it would not right align my triangle. How would I be able to get the numbers to decrease after each row until it reaches 0? Would I have to add another if statement, like if (j > i) ?

Comment: @SteveSteve I just noticed the pattern you want. No, you don't need to add an `if-else` for that. Just alter the numbers `for` loop slightly so that `j` starts from `0` and ends at `size - i`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @SteveSteve You're welcome! We all been there. I still remember struggling with the exact same problem when I started learning. Your question brought up some good memories for me. Happy coding : )